# Python: How to find presence of every list item in string

Tags: python, list, path

What is the most pythonic way to find presence of every directory name `['spam', 'eggs']` in path e.g. `"/home/user/spam/eggs"`

Usage example (doesn't work but explains my case):

```
dirs = ['spam', 'eggs']
path = "/home/user/spam/eggs"
if path.find(dirs):
    print "All dirs are present in the path"
```

Thanks

Comment: What precisely should your output be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### [`set.issubset`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset):

```
>>> set(['spam', 'eggs']).issubset('/home/user/spam/eggs'.split('/'))
True
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks line you want something like...:

```
if all(d in path.split('/') for d in dirs):
   ...
```

This one-liner style is inefficient since it keeps splitting path for each d (and split makes a list, while a set is better for membership checking). Making it into a 2-liner:

```
pathpieces = set(path.split('/'))
if all(d in pathpieces for d in dirs):
   ...
```

vastly improves performance.

Answer (score 2):

```
names = ['spam', 'eggs']
dir   = "/home/user/spam/eggs"

# Split into parts
parts = [ for part in dir.split('/') if part != '' ]

# Rejoin found paths
dirs  = [ '/'.join(parts[0:n]) for (n, name) in enumerate(parts) if name in names ]
```

Edit : If you just want to verify whether all dirs exist:

```
parts = "/home/user/spam/eggs".split('/')

print all(dir in parts for dir in ['spam', 'eggs'])
```

Comment: This will obviously work, but looks quiet complex for such a simple task. Thanks, anyway:)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want?

```
dirs = ['spam', 'eggs']
path = "/home/user/spam/eggs"
present = [dir for dir in dirs if dir in path]
```

Comment: This is actually a great approach if you want to find which items in the list are present in the string.  For are all items present, one of course needs an extra step to compare present against dirs.

Answer (score 0):

A one liner using generators (using textual lookup and not treating names as anything to do with the filesystem - your request is not totally clear to me)

```
[x for x in dirs if x in  path.split( os.sep )]
```